# Why are native node modules always recompiled on npm install?

Tags: node.js, electron, node-gyp, prebuild

I am building an app with [Electron 14](https://www.electronjs.org/blog/electron-14-0), and [node v14.17.7](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v14.17.6/), respectively [npm 6.14.15] to build my native node modules.

Every time I execute `npm install` all my native dependencies are rebuilt from source (since the combination of Electron and node version is not available as a prebuilt in the repo).

Here is an exert from the logs:

```text
• electron-builder  version=22.14.13
  • loaded configuration  file=package.json ("build" field)
  • rebuilding native dependencies  dependencies=drive-name@1.0.3 platform=darwin arch=x64
  • install prebuilt binary  name=foo version=9.2.4 platform=darwin arch=x64 napi=
  • build native dependency from sources  name=foo
                                          version=9.2.4
                                          platform=darwin
                                          arch=x64
                                          napi=
                                          reason=prebuild-install failed with error
                                          (run with env DEBUG=electron-builder to get more information)
    prebuild-install WARN install prebuilt binaries enforced with --force!
    prebuild-install WARN install prebuilt binaries may be out of date!
```

The following message stands out:

```text
WARN install prebuilt binaries enforced with --force!
```

The line is printed [here](https://github.com/prebuild/prebuild-install/blob/5065bce028e36b2b67e9195bc48b9a46784b78ea/bin.js#L47)

```
if (opts.force) {
  log.warn('install', 'prebuilt binaries enforced with --force!')
  log.warn('install', 'prebuilt binaries may be out of date!')
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea or clue where `force` is set to true. Can anyone help?

The `build` field of the package.json is this:

```
"build": {
    "appId": "com.foo.foo",
    "productName": "foo",
    "buildVersion": "1.0.0",
    "publish": {
      "provider": "s3",
      "bucket": "foo",
      "region": "foo",
      "endpoint": "https://foo.s3.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "afterPack": "./scripts/afterPack.js",
    "afterSign": "./scripts/notarization.js",
    "afterAllArtifactBuild": "./scripts/notarization_dmg.js",
    "files": [
      "dist/**/*",
      "main.js",
    ],
    "extraResources": [
      "./extra/**"
    ],
    "dmg": {
      "sign": true
    },
    "mac": {
      "binaries": [
        "./python34/bin/python3.4",
      ],
      "target": [
        "zip",
        "dmg"
      ],
      "hardenedRuntime": true,
      "entitlements": "./scripts/entitlements.mac.plist",
      "icon": "./public/icons/mac/icon.icns"
    },
    "directories": {
      "output": "foo-release",
      "buildResources": "public"
    }
```

Comment: package.json could be helpful maybe it's setup wrong.

Comment: Good idea. Unfortunately, the native module contains no `force` option in the entire source, nor `package.json`, neither does my project.

Comment: Could you share your package.json "build" field as indicated by this part of the log: "file=package.json ("build" field)"?

Comment: I added the `build` field and only removed `win` and `linux` and I had to obfuscate the program name with `foo`

Answer (score 1):

Set `DEBUG=electron-builder` before running npm install to get more info.

Also consider this note from [prebuild-install](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prebuild-install)

> Instead of prebuild paired with prebuild-install, we recommend
> prebuildify paired with node-gyp-build.
>
> With prebuildify, all prebuilt binaries are shipped inside the package
> that is published to npm, which means there's no need for a separate
> download step like you find in prebuild. The irony of this approach is
> that it is faster to download all prebuilt binaries for every platform
> when they are bundled than it is to download a single prebuilt binary
> as an install script.
>
> Upsides:
>
> 1. No extra download step, making it more reliable and faster to install.
> 2. Supports changing runtime versions locally and using the same install between Node.js and Electron. Reinstalling or rebuilding is
>    not necessary, as all prebuilt binaries are in the npm tarball and the
>    correct one is simply picked on runtime.
> 3. The node-gyp-build runtime dependency is dependency-free and will remain so out of principle, because introducing dependencies would
>    negate the shorter install time.
> 4. Prebuilt binaries work even if npm install scripts are disabled.
>    5.The npm package checksum covers prebuilt binaries too.

---

Edit: Try

- setting `"npmRebuild": "false",` in the build field ([via](/q/63023046))
- setting `opts.force = false` at node_modules/[prebuild-install/bin.js:45](https://github.com/prebuild/prebuild-install/blob/5065bce028e36b2b67e9195bc48b9a46784b78ea/bin.js#L45)
- `npm install --verbose` for even more output and
- `npm install --timing`  to save the debug logs for examination afterwards if the former gives too much.
- Making a npm-dbg copy of npm with added `--inspect-brk` at the end between `$NODE` and `$NPM_CLI_JS`. Then use a Chromium browser's [devtools/your IDE](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/#inspector-clients) to step through the install process with hotkeys F10 and F11 in browsers. You can set breakpoints in advance or insert them via `debugger;` and the run 'till there to speedup this process with hotkey F8.
- switching to [prebuildify](https://github.com/prebuild/prebuildify)

Comment: Unfortunately `set DEBUG=electron-builder` does not reveal any further log output that explains this behaviour.

Comment: @DanielStephens Setting `opts.force = false` at node_modules/prebuild-install/bin.js:45 should disable the native build. Does this work?